# How to hide JavaScripts in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have inserted my javascripts in the header.php file, but I noticed the whole code can be stolen by simply lookin at the source from within any single post or homepage...

May you suggest me a simple way to hide my javascripts in wordpress somehow to prevent being copied/stolen?

Comment: Can't be done. JavaScript runs on the client and therefore must be visible

Comment: It can however be uglified, makes it less readable

Comment: @Andreas let me correct myself then. *even less readable

Comment: Haha! But to OP. You can include the JavaScript file in the source and that makes only a link to the file visible, but still anyone that wants to read it can read it by opening the file

Answer (score 3):

You can't hide javascript. Client always need to access it.

Answer (score 1):

You can minify and uglyfy your code, so it will be hard to read it